# Evaluate the integral $ \int \frac{\sec ^2(x)}{(x+5)^2(x-1)}dx $

Tags: integration

I have learned integration by parts, integration by u-substitution, partial fractions, power rule, integrals of $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$, the derivatives of the standard trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions.

But I have no idea how to solve this question, Please let me know if I need to learn more information to solve this question such as learning special non-elementary integrals (by the way, I have no idea how to tell whether or not an integral is elementary except that all integrals of rational polynomial functions are elementary).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use an approximation to evaluate this, I don't think this can be done using calculus

Comment: its an indefinite integral questions though

Comment: What's the full question? Is it just to solve the integral? An approximation of the integral? Or some other problem that eventually led you to this integral?

Comment: What context do you require the integral for, because how you would evaluate it depends on what it needs for. You could always use a Taylor expansion and Binomial expansion if you need it

Comment: The question is just to integrate it in the same way that you are able to integrate the function 2x^2. But, since this question has no closed form expression, the question is to express it with special integrals such as exponential integral, hyperbolic integrals etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am skeptical about a possible closed form (even using special functions.

Assuminf that you want to compute
$$I=\int_0^a \frac{\sec ^2(x)}{(x+5)^2(x-1)}\,dx$$ with $a<1$, just use Taylor series built at $x=0$ to get
$$\frac{\sec ^2(x)}{(x+5)^2(x-1)}=-\frac{1}{25}-\frac{3 x}{125}-\frac{43 x^2}{625}-\frac{161 x^3}{3125}-\frac{781
   x^4}{9375}-\frac{5569 x^5}{78125}-\frac{316168 x^6}{3515625}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ and integrate termwise to get
$$I=-\frac{a}{25}-\frac{3 a^2}{250}-\frac{43 a^3}{1875}-\frac{161 a^4}{12500}-\frac{781
   a^5}{46875}-\frac{5569 a^6}{468750}-\frac{316168
   a^7}{24609375}+O\left(a^{8}\right)$$

The table below reports values of the above expression and the result of the numerical integration
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.05 & -0.0020330  & -0.0020330 \\
 0.10 & -0.0041444  & -0.0041444 \\
 0.15 & -0.0063553  & -0.0063553 \\
 0.20 & -0.0086903  & -0.0086904 \\
 0.25 & -0.0111786  & -0.0111788 \\
 0.30 & -0.0138555  & -0.0138564 \\
 0.35 & -0.0167642  & -0.0167677 \\
 0.40 & -0.0199578  & -0.0199688 \\
 0.45 & -0.0235021  & -0.0235326 \\
 0.50 & -0.0274783  & -0.0275554 \\
 0.55 & -0.0319871  & -0.0321682 \\
 0.60 & -0.0371524  & -0.0375539 \\
 0.65 & -0.0431263 & -0.0439777 \\
 0.70 & -0.0500947 & -0.0518410 \\
 0.75 & -0.0582835 & -0.0617866
\end{array}
\right)$$ It is clear that the approximation starts to be bad when $a$ increases. But you could add more terms.

Comment: Is it possible to express the indefinite integral in the form of other special integrals like a hyperbolic integral or something?                                                 Btw, the question was under the category indefinite integrals not definite integrals (otherwise I would've use Riemann sums or something)